# Finding/Loading Files using File ID instead of names in Google Collab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Newbie to python. Am writing a small python script to read/write mp3 tag details to files in a google folder. However, am not able to figure out how to load the file using the file id. Including the code snippet.

Find / Load a file using only fileID. If I put in the file name the code works. But I do not have file names as these are uploaded by users.

Alternatively, if I could get a fileName using fileID that would be great as well !

Thanks in advance !

```
# Step 1 - Install and Initialize all Libraries
!pip install eyed3
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
!pip install validators

import os
import eyed3
import pandas as pd
import gspread
import validators #for validation if a string is a URL
import sys
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import drive
from google.colab import auth

# Step 2 - Authenticate
auth.authenticate_user()
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Step 3 -

sDirName = "/content/drive/My Drive/Please attach MP3 audio file (File responses)/"
sFileID = "Google Sheet File ID here"
tgtSheet = 'Sheet1'
sColName = 'File ID'

# Step 4 - read sheet and extract tags 
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
os.listdir(sDirName)

for ind in df.index:
  try:
    if ind != 0 :
        mediaID = df[sColName][ind] ## using file id would be good but unable to figure out.
        audiofile = eyed3.load(os.path.join(sDirName, mediaID))
        worksheet.update_cell((ind+1), iColDuration, audiofile.info.time_secs/86400)
        worksheet.update_cell((ind+1), iColBitRate, audiofile.info.bit_rate_str)
        worksheet.update_cell((ind+1), iColTitle, audiofile.tag.title)
    except:
      worksheet.update_cell((ind+1), iColDuration, 'Not Found - ' + str(ind+1))
      pass
```